# How to limit the memory usage of chrome on a Mac?

Tags: macos, memory, google-chrome

I have 6 GB memory on my MacBook Pro but after some time I started Chrome, it ate up around 3-4 GB of my memory. Is there any way to limit the memory usage of Chrome?

P.S. for Mac, it seems there's no way to set the start-up arguments for Chrome, nor have a "purge memory" button in the task manager. So the usual ways for Windows don't apply for Mac.

Comment: Are you running a ton of addons?

Comment: Macs are very different from Windows PCs in terms of memory management. Are you experiencing any performance problems? Which version of chrome do you have? How many tabs are open?

Comment: 17.0.963.2, around 20 tabs and 10 plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually on a mac there is a nifty little command for the command line that will attempt to `purge` the unused inactive memory.

```
purge
```

I have run into the same problem. That is only a temporary fix though.

**NOTE:** When you enter it don't worry if it seems as if your comp froze, that is normal as far as I have noticed, and will go away once the `purge` program has finished.

Comment: all `purge` does is wipe your in-memory disk cache.  that disk cache automatically purges as needed.   `purge` doesnt actually help with high memory consumption of apps such as chrome (or other memory leaks..)

Comment: not to mention that this in no way addresses the question of "how to limit the memory usage".....

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way chrome forks a new process for each tab, it can report that its using more than its actually using.  Some memory is shared between the chrome processes.  Check the about:memory link in chrome, to see how much memory is actually being used.